# Need to retrieve original data shape from one hot encoding shape

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, statsmodels, data-preprocessing

I received a dataset that include columns that previously transformed into one hot encoded. And I want to retrieve the old shape of it to do some preprocessing and filling NAs methods and of course read the stats model of the dataset.

The data columns I got:

| team2_offensive_derived_var_0 | team2_offensive_derived_var_1 | team2_offensive_derived_var_2 | team2_offensive_derived_var_3 | team2_offensive_derived_var_4 | team2_offensive_derived_var_5 | team2_offensive_derived_var_6 | team2_offensive_derived_var_7 | team2_offensive_derived_var_8 | team2_offensive_derived_var_9 | team2_offensive_derived_var_10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

I want to transform it's shape into

| row_id | team2_offensive_derived |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | var 10 |
| 1 | var 9 |
| 2 | var 8 |
| 3 | var 7 |
| 4 | var 6 |
| 5 | var 5 |
| 6 | var 4 |
| 7 | var 3 |
| 8 | var 2 |
| 9 | var 1 |
| 10 | var 0 |

I also got a columns like:

| team2_other_ratio_var_42 | team2_other_ratio_var_43 | team2_other_ratio_var_44 | team2_other_ratio_var_45 | team2_other_ratio_var_46 | team2_other_ratio_var_47 | team2_other_ratio_var_48 | team2_other_ratio_var_49 | team2_other_ratio_var_50 | team2_other_ratio_var_51 | team2_other_ratio_var_52 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.0 | 0.400 | 0.200 | 0.000 | 0.750 | 0.250 | 0.341121 | 0.375 | 0.354167 | 0.184211 | 0.000 |

But I'm confused how should I retrieve it to it's original shape? "Categorical" But I don't know how?

Thank you all for your help

Comment: `But I'm confused how should I retrieve it to it's original shape? "Categorical" But I don't know how?` - what is expected ouput?

Comment: I'm still struggling with the original shape and I don't know what is original shape of the data.

Comment: So there is one row DataFrame with `0` and floats, what is logic for get original shape?

Comment: So, I guess I will leave this. But I wanted to minimize the number of columns to preprocess the data properly. As I told you, I'm trying to figure out what should I do.

Comment: It is one row DataFrame and need remove columns with `0` in data?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `stack`:

```
cols = ['row_id', 'team2_offensive_derived']
out = df.replace(0, pd.NA).stack().rename_axis(cols).reset_index()[cols]
```

output:

```
    row_id         team2_offensive_derived
0        0  team2_offensive_derived_var_10
1        1   team2_offensive_derived_var_9
2        2   team2_offensive_derived_var_8
3        3   team2_offensive_derived_var_7
4        4   team2_offensive_derived_var_6
5        5   team2_offensive_derived_var_5
6        6   team2_offensive_derived_var_4
7        7   team2_offensive_derived_var_3
8        8   team2_offensive_derived_var_2
9        9   team2_offensive_derived_var_1
10      10   team2_offensive_derived_var_0
```

With different column names:

```
out = (df
       .replace(0, pd.NA)
       .rename(columns=lambda x: x.replace('team2_offensive_derived_', ''))
       .stack()
       .rename_axis(cols)
       .reset_index()[cols]
      )
```

output:

```
    row_id team2_offensive_derived
0        0                  var_10
1        1                   var_9
2        2                   var_8
3        3                   var_7
4        4                   var_6
5        5                   var_5
6        6                   var_4
7        7                   var_3
8        8                   var_2
9        9                   var_1
10      10                   var_0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
#split by last previous _
df.columns = df.columns.str.rsplit('_', 2, expand=True)
#replace 0 to NaNs, so reshape remove rows with 0
df = df.replace(0, np.nan).stack([1,2])
#join MultiIndex value
df.index = df.index.map(lambda x: f'{x[1]} {x[2]}')
#create DataFrame
df = df.index.to_frame(name='team2_offensive_derived',index=False)

print (df)
   team2_offensive_derived
0                   var 10
1                    var 9
2                    var 8
3                    var 7
4                    var 6
5                    var 5
6                    var 4
7                    var 3
8                    var 2
9                    var 1
10                   var 0
```